# Delay-Loaded UserControl/Page in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I couldn't find a right term to search about this in the feature.

I have a control that will load a very heavy data that embedding within a tab of of my MainWindow.

Test Case:
For testing I have a window, within this windows there are 2 tab. the first tab contain notthing. 2nd tab contain this user control.

In the 2nd tab I have a `MessageBox`.

Run this program and MessageBox popup right after the MainWindow was loaded.

How can I delay load this usercontrol/page until the tab is active?

Comment: What is your design (MVVM, or simple event-based WPF app, or...).  One consideration is to load the data object of the user control in its own thread during startup.

Comment: The data load in different thread is one thing, but the other thing is to have it running only when user need to view it. How can I archive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried calling your load code only when the user control is visible?

The other suggestion would be to create you own tab control that only loads the content when the tab is visible. This would also allow you to create animations when a tab becomes hidden before the new tab is visible.